# Deleting a element if it contains something using jQuery in GreaseMonkey

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

It's a JQuery code that I'm using for GreaseMonkey.
This is my script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Delete test
// @namespace   nope
// @description hi der
// @include     *.*
// @version     1
// @require http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
// @grant       none

// JQUERY 
[insert jquery.min.js here]
// JQUERY 

var item = $(':contains(ANCHORFREE_VERSION=)');
$item.empty();
// ==/UserScript==
```

I have no idea why it's not working.

EDIT: I'm trying to remove all scripts that contain that text.

Comment: What exectly do you mean by "not working"? What are you trying to achieve? What is the expected result? Please be specific.

Comment: did you have a friendly talk with the console?

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to wrong variable:

```
var item = $(':contains(ANCHORFREE_VERSION=)');
item.empty(); // <----should be item instead of $item.
```

Comment: Now it deletes all the content on my page, what is happening?